# Storing permissions using powers of two: Possible to create a View?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table `DocumentTypes`:

```
TypeID | Document Type
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
1      | Type1
2      | Type2
3      | Type3
4      | Type4
```

I am creating a table, `Permission`:

```
UserID | Permission
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
ID1    | ???
ID2    |
ID3    |
```

The plan is to calculate `Permission = Sum{2^(TypeID)}`.

So to if  `User1` were to need permission to `Type1`,`Type3`,`Type4`, I would store `2+8+16 = 26`.

Everything is set up to both add and remove permissions in this way.  I can use a `Stored Procedure` to view the permissions (with each permission in its own row).

***Is there a way to do this with a `View` instead of a `Stored Procedure`?***

Comment: Can you add the code for your procedure?

Comment: If you want to view each permission in its own row, then why don't you store it that way?. I suggest you use a table with the UserId and DocumentType as a key or something.

Comment: Lamak: to be honest, it is probably somewhat hard to justify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bit-masks.

If you use a BITWISE AND with a BITMASK, you get just the bits you are interested in.  So, if `(x & 2) = 2`, you know the `2 bit` of `x` is set.  Using that, you can do this...

```
SELECT
  value,
  CASE WHEN (value &  1) =  1 THEN 'flag01 set' ELSE '-' END       AS flag01,
  CASE WHEN (value &  2) =  2 THEN 'flag02 set' ELSE '-' END       AS flag02,
  CASE WHEN (value &  4) =  4 THEN 'flag04 set' ELSE '-' END       AS flag04,
  CASE WHEN (value &  8) =  8 THEN 'flag08 set' ELSE '-' END       AS flag08,
  CASE WHEN (value & 16) = 16 THEN 'flag16 set' ELSE '-' END       AS flag16,
FROM
  permissions
```

If you want to make each those their own row, either PIVOT it, or join on a table that list the permissions and the bit-mask they use...

```
SELECT
  [p].*,
  CASE WHEN ([p].value & [f].mask) = [f].mask THEN [f].name ELSE '-' END  AS flag
FROM
  permissions         AS [p]
CROSS JOIN
  flags               AS [f]
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solution!  The second option that you listed is what I used.  I replaced `flags` with a subselect from the `DocumentType` table (`Power(2,TypeID)` as `mask`) and added a `where` clause to only include rows that matched a `DocumentType`